# A sum of subharmonic and superharmonic function that is subharmonic

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, probability-theory, potential-theory

Suppose $u$ and $v$ are subharmonic on a bounded domain $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $n\geq2$, and $w=u-v.$ If $w$ is also subharmonic and defined everywhere on $G$ (we exclude the case $u$ or $v$ is harmonic), can we say that $u$ and $v$ differ by a constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I have misunderstood the question but if $v,w$ are (finite) subharmonic and $u=v+w$ then the hypothesis is satisfied, right?

Comment: Thanks for noticing it. You are right! I edited and excluded this case.

Comment: @M.Rahmat That doesn't make any difference. Sum of two subharmonic functions is subharmonic . I have changed harmonic to subharmonic in my answer.